# How can I disable FRP Lock on my Samsung Tab A6 without the ability to start the device?

Tags: odin, frp, samsung-galaxy-tab-a

When I try to start my device it's in a boot-loop. And I also can't access the recovery menu
(which you can enter with Power + Home Button + Volume UP). So I can only enter the download mode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Enter the download mode using Home + Volume Down + Power and flash stock ROM using odin... That's the only solution to get your device working back.

Comment: Thank you. But when I try it fail's and I get this error message in Odin: "<ID:0/003> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)"